# Why can't the noclobber variable protect you from overwriting an existing file with cp or mv?

Tags: bash, cp, mv

Why can t the noclobber variable protect you from overwriting an existing file with cp or mv?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because `noclobber` is functionality internal to the shell, whereas `cp` and `mv` are programs that are external to the shell, and wouldn't (and shouldn't) know about what goes on in the shell.

To make an analogy, your question is a bit like asking why the default font settings in Excel don't affect Word.

To be specific, what `noclobber` actually does do is it instructs the shell to not overwrite files *as a result of output redirection*, as when you run a command such as `ls >files`. The redirection of the output to `files` is a function carried out by the shell itself, and therefore it makes sense for it to be configurable in the shell.

On the other hand, `cp` and `mv` have their own functionality to do the same thing: You can call them with the `-n` switch to make them fail instead of clobber files. (Or with the `-i` switch to ask interactively before clobbering.)

Comment: Excellent answer. You may want to give an example where noclobber works, such as output redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Also, even `tee` won't honor the `noclobber` option, if set. For e.g.

```
[ankur@server1 ~]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>


[ankur@server1 ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

[ankur@server1 ~]$ set -o | grep noclobber 
noclobber       on
[ankur@server1 ~]$ echo hi | tee myfile
hi
[ankur@server1 ~]$ ls -i myfile 
19731252 myfile
[ankur@server1 ~]$ cat myfile 
hi
[ankur@server1 ~]$ echo hiii | tee myfile
hiii
[ankur@server1 ~]$ ls -i myfile 
19731252 myfile
[ankur@server1 ~]$ cat myfile 
hiii
```